# How to construct a LINQ Query to test a list against another list where elements start with the elements from the other

Tags: c#, linq

Basically, I am constructing an autocomplete textbox to search for name fragments. (Yes could have used Lucene or etc but due to many non-technical reasons, not using it)

```
public IEnumerable<ContactAutoComplete> SelectActiveContactsAutoCompleteForMailingList(string fullName)
  {
    //Search query fullname e.g. James Francis Cameron is decomposed 
    //into a list comprising James, Francis, Cameron
      IEnumerable<string> fragment = fullName.Trim().Split();

      return _db.Contacts.Where(contact => contact.Status == Statuses.Activated &&
      (fragment.All(c => contact.FullName.Trim().Split().Any(frag => 
      frag.StartsWith(c))
  }
```

What I need in the above context is a clause to

- Apply the `.Trim()` and `.Split()` to the FullName field of each contact
- Test the obtained list of text fragments (contact.FullName.Trim.Split) against the text fragments (fragment) obtained from the search query
- Check if each text fragment (fragment) will appear at the start of each of fragments obtained from `contact.FullName.Trim.Split`

Examples:
In the database, a contact has the FullName, James Francis Cameron

Searching for
"Fra Cam" - OK

"Cam Fra" - OK (because in Asia, name ordering convention is inconsistent)

"Cis Ron" - not OK

Many thanks!

Comment: If you're making a DB call you will not want to try to do `Trim()` and `Split()` on the DB records as LINQ will not be able to translate those to SQL. For this capability you would need to have two fields, one for first name and one for last name

Answer (score 0):

Linq can't translate methods like `string.Split()` to SQL, so you can't do it in a super general way like this, and you can't easily split the Full Name into two fields while doing a query. If you have your name in two fields for first and last name you can do this:

```
var fragments = fullName.Split(' ');
var first = fragments.FirstOrDefault().Trim();
var last = fragments.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Trim();
var r = db.Contacts.Where(x => (x.First.StartsWith(first) && x.Last.StartsWith(last)) 
    ||  (x.First.StartsWith(last) && x.Last.StartsWith(first)) 
);
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply. But here there is an arbitrary number of fragments. For example people with longer names like Franklin Delano Roosevelt (thats three fragments) or even Musk Elon (for example)